# Not able to call an extern function

Tags: c

I want to call a function that reside in my func.c file into my main.c
This is my func.c

```
#include "func.h"
int func(int i) {
return ++i ;
}
```

This is my header file func.h

```
int func(int i);
```

And this is my main code: main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func.h"    
main()
{
   int res = func(3);
   printf("%d\n",res);  
system("pause");
}
```

Compiling the main code I get the error: undefined reference to 'func'
My goal is to call function from an external file (that is not part of the same compilation unit).
How to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You don't get an error while compiling. You get an error while *linking*.

Comment: Have you tried `#include "func.h"` instead of `#include <func.h>` in `main.c`?

Comment: @AlterMann Completely irrelevant. Headers files don't affect linkage in C.

Comment: @OP: You have to link together both files. Something like `gcc -o progname main.c func.c`.

Comment: or use `gcc -c main.c` if you'd wanted to do the linking in a separate step

Comment: Disagree w the duplicate vote, that Q/A is so big that it is hard for OP to pick his/her problem out from all the other problems

Comment: @MattMcNabb so hard to copy-pasta the error message verbatim into Google, right?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant re. your comment on the now-deleted post: if a `#include` directive cannot open the file named in the directive then compilation should fail. There's no "optional includes" in C. (well - the standard doesn't say that unambiguously, but all compilers behave that way).

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func.h"    // change ( since func.h is not a slandered header file its a user define header file)  
main()
{
   int res = func(3);
   printf("%d\n",res);  
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The inclusion of the header file has nothing to do with the linker error. It won't cause it, it won't resolve it.

Comment: as you mentioned in your earlier comments that we can link both the file using gcc -o progname main.c func.c or or use gcc -c main.c but if you try to compile using any of these you will hit the error "func.h no such file or dir"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidPostill Where do you see the request for clarification?

Comment: @Tom It is the default text that is added when flagging an answer that doesn't answer the question but may be a valid comment ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I know that this is a standard text and I still don't know why you've choosed that and why this is not an answer. It might be a bad one, but still an "answer".

Comment: It doesn't help either.

Comment: @Tom I didn't flag it as "not an answer". That is a different flag. I flagged it because it doesn't actually answer the question, but it **could** be a valid **comment**.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, when you can explain why it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Tom Please see the rest of the comments and the edit to the question. `#include "func.h"` hasn't fixed the problem ...

Comment: @DavidPostill And? As I said, it might be a bad/wrong answer and it might deserve downvotes for that, but this doesn't justify the flags. I guess we both have different opinions in that case and won't get an agreement.